# c# Gap between controls with autoscroll=true

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, panel, space

I have a panel that has **autoscroll** set to **true**. This panel contains other panels that get positioned dynamically.

```
parent.Size = new Size((f.Width - 50) + 18, f.Height - 100);
parent.Location = new Point(50, 100);
parent.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(parent_MouseClick);
parent.Scroll += new ScrollEventHandler(parent_Scroll);
parent.AutoScroll = true;

f.Controls.Add(parent);

...More Code...

int top = 5, left = 5;

foreach (string file in files)
    {
        Panel d = new Panel();
        d.Size = new Size(parent.Width / 5 - 10, 100);//Image Height: 70px
        d.Location = new Point(left, top);
        d.Tag = file;
        d.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(item_MouseEnter);
        d.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(item_MouseLeave);
        d.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;

        ...More Code...

        if (left + (d.Width * 2) + 5 >= parent.Width)
        {
            top += d.Height + 5;
            left = 5;
        }
        else
            left += d.Width + 5;

        Application.OpenForms["MDC_Explorer"].Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
        {
            parent.Controls.Add(d);
        }));
    }
```

I have tried to add **parent.AutoScrollPosition.Y** to **top** *(top += d.Height + 5)* but gaps still appear between the panels. The gaps only appear vertically so i'm guessing it has something to do with the **parent** scroll value and **top** but I can't, after 3 hours, figure it out.

Some un-shown variables:

```
Form f; //The main Form (MDC_Explorer)
var files; //Just an array of strings
```

Comment: Have you considered of using `FlowLayoutPanel` / `TableLayoutPanel` to perform all layouting automatically? It looks like a list, perhaps you should rather use dedicated for displaying lists control (`ListBox` /  `ListView`) instead of creating lots of `Panel`s ?

Comment: I would expect this `top += d.Height + 5;`  to create a gap of 4 between the panels. Is that the gap you observe? I do not see what autoscroll has to do with it; does it change the result?

Comment: Well hey... Changing it to a `FlowLayoutPanel` fixed that problem. Just one other thing how can I prevent flickering when you scroll fast.